# Two instances of PostgreSQL switching on system restart

Tags: macos, postgresql

I have had two system restart events where after reboot the databases in Postgres have changed. Now I have two different instances and have databases in each, but I do not know how to get to the other set.

Is there a command to change to other PostgreSQL instances on a server? How do I stop it switching?

I am using psql (9.3.4, server 9.3.2) on Mac OSX v10.9.4. I am using port 5432.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: How'd you install each PostgreSQL instance and from where?

Comment: Craig Ringer, One installation was from OSGeo, the other I can't really remember. Think it Postgres.app So one was an application install. You started to work through my previous post but we never finished. Its happened again and I have not been able to find any solutions.

Comment: The simple solution is likely to be to change one of them to port 5433. What previous question? (link)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24848911/cant-find-my-databases-after-power-cut-and-reboot  Craig Ringer

Comment: Can anyone take me through the process? I seem to have a hard time finding the right info to get the job done!